# C++ use pointer to struct in function

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, parameters, reference

I am trying to us a pointer to a struct in C++. I have struct wSignal with member MAC. I give the pointer of a struct to the function.

Definition struct:

```
struct wSignal
{
    std::string MAC;
};
```

using the function:

```
wSignal it1 = {"22:44:66:AA:BB:CC"};
DoesPeriodExist(&it1);
```

definition of the function:

```
bool DoesPeriodExist (wSignal& s)
{
   if(it1->MAC != "")
}
```

Error I get:

```
error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘wSignal’
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I use the pointer? Sorry if this is a silly questions. I am not very familiar with pointers and am trying the understand the concept.

Comment: Call it with `DoesPeriodExist(it1);`; The reference is already in the definition of the function argument,.

Comment: `wSignal&` specifies a reference type, not a pointer

Comment: A pointer to `struct wSignal` is `wSignal *s`.

Comment: Do you mean `if(it1->MAC != "")` in the function - or `if(s->MAC != "")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're declaring the parameter as a reference (to `wSignal`), not a pointer, for this case you should change the function to

```
bool DoesPeriodExist (wSignal& s)
{
   if(s.MAC != "") ...
}
```

and pass the argument like

```
wSignal it1 = {"22:44:66:AA:BB:CC"};
DoesPeriodExist(it1);
```

If you want to go with pointer, then the parameter type should be changed to the pointer (to `wSignal`)

```
bool DoesPeriodExist (wSignal* s)
{
   if(s->MAC != "")
}
```

and pass the argument like your code showed

```
wSignal it1 = {"22:44:66:AA:BB:CC"};
DoesPeriodExist(&it1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are giving a *pointer* to `struct` to a function that expects a *reference* to a `struct`.

This is a mismatch that needs to be fixed:

- You can pass the `struct` itself, `DoesPeriodExist(it1)`, or
- You can accept a pointer, `bool DoesPeriodExist (wSignal* s)`

The first approach is preferable in situations when `wSignal` must be non-null. If you wish to allow passing `NULL` to `DoesPeriodExist`, only the second approach will work, because `NULL` references are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of `DoesPeriodExist()` does not expect a pointer but a reference to a `wSignal`. The correct signature would be

```
bool DoesPeriodExist(wSignal* s)
```

Thus the base operand in your implementation is not a pointer but a reference, which is used with the `.` operator.